# Past Perfect or Past Simple

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past

I want to understand if we need to keep using past perfect in a long sentence. (in speaking and writing english)

For example,

"I want to tell you a story that happened to me in summer. I started to hang out with a girl in July, we had been friends for about 3 years at that point, we had even dated once in 2017"

or

"I want to tell you a story that happened to me in summer. I started to hang out with a girl in July, we had been friends for about 3 years at that point, we even dated once in 2017"

Comment: I think once you place the events in context of the past it gets cluttered adding all the passed perfect furniture. It would still be understood if you just kept it as past.

Comment: I think your examples would be clearer if they were punctuated as sentences.